# Loading images in tensorflow queue provides random image instead of FIFO

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load an image with tensorflow, but I need the files to be in order.  When I load the image it loads a random image but not in the order I provided through my initial array.  However, my understanding is that string_input_producer(file_names) is FIFO.  Why are my images random and how do I make it load images in order?

```
with open("name.json", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    file_names = []
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        load_location = row['location']
        file_names.append(load_location)

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(file_names) #  list of files to read
    count_num_files = tf.size(file_names)


    reader=tf.WholeFileReader()
    key,value=reader.read(filename_queue)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(value)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        num_files = sess.run(count_num_files)
        for i in range(num_files):
            # this does not match
            location = file_names[i]
            # with this image
            image_eval=img.eval()
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake, string_input_producer shuffle setting defaults to True:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(file_names, shuffle=False)
```